# Can we use Javascript EventSource for unicast?

Tags: javascript, server

I have set up a Rails server that handles requests from EventSource in Javascript. The problem is that it broadcasts the message to every subscribed client. Is there any way I can send a message that only arrives at a specific subscribed client? Like using some token or ID..